# Extracting SquashFS based filesystem

Tags: mips, binwalk

I'm trying to use binwalk to extract the firmware for the Ubiquiti Networks ER-X. Currently I've downloaded a copy of the firmware and uncompressed it. I opened the folder with the filesystem contents and found `compat squashfs.tmp squashfs.tmp.md5 version.tmp vmlinux.tmp vmlinux.tmp.md5`. I checked to see which file was the biggest and found `squashfs.tmp` to be the biggest at about 78MB in size. I ran binwalk with the -e flag but that didn't extract the filesystem. Link to the [firmware](https://www.ubnt.com/download/edgemax/edgerouter-x/default/edgerouter-er-xer-x-sfpep-r6-firmware-v1107).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to extract the file system just fine. I used Binwalk v2.1.2b and have `sasquatch` installed.

Extracted file system:

```
_squashfs.tmp.extracted/squashfs-root $ ls
bin  boot  config  dev  etc  home  lib  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  root.dev  run  sbin  selinux  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

It is indeed for a MIPS device:

```
$ file bin/bash
bin/bash: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, MIPS, MIPS-II version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, BuildID[sha1]=1b20797b11fa0a481a334f911ac5dfa27ce20c75, stripped
```

Make sure all of your tools are up to date and you have the necessary plugins installed. From the [installation page](https://github.com/ReFirmLabs/binwalk/blob/master/INSTALL.md):

> Binwalk relies on multiple external utilties in order to automatically
>   extract/decompress files and data:
>
> ```
> # Install standard extraction utilities
> $ sudo apt-get install mtd-utils gzip bzip2 tar arj lhasa p7zip p7zip-full cabextract cramfsprogs cramfsswap squashfs-tools sleuthkit default-jdk lzop srecord
>
> # Install sasquatch to extract non-standard SquashFS images
> $ sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev liblzo2-dev
> $ git clone https://github.com/devttys0/sasquatch
> $ (cd sasquatch && ./build.sh)
>
> # Install jefferson to extract JFFS2 file systems
> $ sudo pip install cstruct
> $ git clone https://github.com/sviehb/jefferson
> $ (cd jefferson && sudo python setup.py install)
> ```

Comment: I am using MacOS but thanks for the response. The Binwalk version I'm running is v2.1.1. I ran "brew upgrade binwalk" and brew said that was the latest version.

Comment: Do you have a tool that can extract SquashFS file systems? Such as `unsquashfs`  or `sasquatch`? `binwalk` uses `sasquatch` to extract SquashFS file systems, so unless you have that installed on your Mac you will need to extract it some other way. If you have access to a linux box (such as a VM), installation of everything you need is trivial, as the installation page indicates.

Comment: I wanted to just use the MacOS environment but I guess I will half to get a Docker container setup for running binwalk. It's a shame because I quite like homebrew.